# GeoDistance and Excel export

Tags: export, units

I'm trying to export the distance matrix below to an excel file. I have no interested on the unit. I just care the value of a distance. A standard export command does not work properly. 
How should I proceed?

Thanks

```
SelectedCities = {Entity[
    "City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"LosAngeles", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Chicago", "Illinois", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Houston", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Philadelphia", "Pennsylvania", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}]};
CityNameList = #1 & @@@ Transpose[{CommonName@SelectedCities}];
MyDistanceMatrix = DistanceMatrix[GeoPosition[SelectedCities]];
Export["~/Desktop/InputFileChapter3.xlsx", MyDistanceMatrix, "XLSX"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`QuantityMagnitude`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html) to extract the numerical value from a [`Quantity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html):

```
SelectedCities = {
   Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"LosAngeles", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Chicago", "Illinois", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Houston", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Philadelphia", "Pennsylvania", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}]};
CityNameList = #1 & @@@ Transpose[{CommonName@SelectedCities}];
MyDistanceMatrix = QuantityMagnitude[
   DistanceMatrix[GeoPosition[SelectedCities]], 
  "Kilometers"
 ]
(* {{0., 3966.05, 1157.99, 2286.3, 124.884, 4147.89},
    {3966.05, 0., 2820.05, 2223.06, 3869.84, 551.621},
    {1157.99, 2820.05, 0., 1506.58, 1075.28, 2990.05},
    {2286.3, 2223.06, 1506.58, 0., 2163.45, 2646.14},
    {124.884, 3869.84, 1075.28, 2163.45, 0., 4063.58},
    {4147.89, 551.621, 2990.05, 2646.14, 4063.58, 0.}} *)
```

Exporting should now work as expected.

Comment: It works great! thanks!

Comment: @Lukas Lang: How do you export data to several "Worksheets" in a given Excel file?

Comment: @TugrulTemel See [this example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/XLSX.html#932961803) from the documentation on the `"XLSX"` file format